# Setting up a Hadoop Cluster on Amazon Web services with EBS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, hadoop, hdfs, impala

I was wondering how I could setup a hadoop cluster (say 5 nodes) through AWS. I know how to create the cluster on EC2 but I don't know how to face the following challenges.

1. What happens if I lose my spot instance. How do I keep the cluster going.
2. I am working with some datasets of Size 1TB. Would it be possible to setup the EBS accordingly. How can I access the HDFS in this scenario.

Any help will be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, these suggestions would change. However, assuming a 2 Master and 3 Worker setup, you can probably use r3 instances for Master nodes as they are memory intensive app optimized and go for d2 instances for the worker nodes. d2 instances have multiple local disks and thus can withstand some disk failures while still keeping your data safe.
To answer your specific questions,

1. treat Hadoop machines as any linux applications. What would happen if your general centOS spot instances are lost? Hwnce, generally it is advised to use reserved instances.
2. Hadoop typically stores data by maintaining 3 copies and distributing them across the worker nodes in forms of 128 or 256 MB blocks. So, you will have 3TB data to store across the three worker nodes. Obviously, you have to consider some overhead while calculating space requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS's EMR service - it is designed especially for Hadoop clusters on top of EC2 instances.
It it fully managed, and it comes pre-packed with all the services you need in Hadoop.

Regarding your questions:

There are three main types of nodes in hadoop:

**Master** - a single node, don't need to spot it.

**Core** - a node that handle tasks, and have part of the HDFS

**Task** - a node that handle tasks, but does not have any part of the HDFS

If Task nodes are lost (if they are spot instances) the cluster will continue to work with no problems.

Regarding storage, the default replication factor in EMR is as follows:

1 for clusters < four nodes

2 for clusters < ten nodes

3 for all other clusters

But you can change it - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hdfs-config.html